# MariaDB Galera Cluster Node accesses disk a lot which leads to a massively degraded performance

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb, galera

We have a three node mariadb galera cluster, 3 ubuntu 20 VMs running on different physical servers, and one nodes can only process around half the queries, but has at least tripple the CPU load as each of the other two nodes. The three nodes run on similar hardware, have an identical config (i checked the mariadb configs as well as all server vars), and the VM parameters are identical. After a lot of searching I narrowed down the issue to disk access that only happens on the degraded node. On the other nodes, I do not see any of these. Using iotop, I see the following:

EDIT: I have identified a long running query on the degraded node. However, the same query is very fast on the other two nodes. How is that possible? Query cache is fully disabled.

[image]

[image: issue]

How can I narrow this down further? What could be the issue?

Comment: Check/enable the slow query log. Also look at `show processlist` on the running server to see if there's long running queries compared to other nodes. As all data will be the same it might be the index statistics for the relevant tables aren't up to date (ref: [analyze table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/analyze-table/)).

Comment: @danblack You are right, I have identified one type of long running query on the degraded node. However, the other nodes all process this query as well, to the same amount, but on them, it's not long running. How can a query take very long on one node and be very fast on a different node?

Comment: Try using EXPLAIN to report the optimizer plan for this query on each node. Depending on the quantity of data on each node, or even the data values compared to the specific values you search for, the optimizer might choose different indexes, and that could cause a big difference in performance.

Comment: Is the busy node swapping?

Comment: Every write query is effectively written on every node.  However, the node you connect to usually has to do "more work" to perform the query.  Are you saying that when you _connect_ to a different node, a similar query runs much faster?

Comment: In keeping with Bill's comment, do `ANALYZE TABLE` on the slow server for each table involved in the slow query.

Comment: We might some more clues if we could see the query.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments I was able to solve the problem, thank you all very much:

1. I started with enabling slow query log, and found one particular slow query on the degraded node. The exact same query worked fine on the other nodes.
2. I analyzed this query on the different nodes using ANALYZE and EXPLAIN, and noticed that on the degraded node, indexes were not used, and therefore, filesort happend on disk (reason for the IO threads).
3. I also noticed during step 2 that the degraded node did not have the same amount of rows as the other nodes in the cluster, in certain tables, which was quite a weird discovery
4. Investigating this more revealed that the problem was caused by a missing param during export of the database from the development env.
5. If somebody wants to export a database from the dev. env. via phpmyadmin, and import it into a cluster, you absolutely must check the option "IF NOT EXIST". If this is not checked, the import will be corrupted without you knowing (silent).
6. I reimported the new database and everything works fine now.

Comment: Good process of discovery. I suspect there some other aspect of the phpmyadmin dump that affect the ability of galera to replicate the imported data to other nodes. The `IF NOT EXISTS` might have resolved effect, but I'd look carefully at the dump for things that disable binary logging (`sql_log_bin` or `wsrep_on`). Welcome to SO.  Please also note [dba stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) for purely DB questions. Feel free to ask about any slow queries or anything else you are having trouble with.